# How do I use an API like VNDB?

Tags: json, api, endpoint

I'm used to sending a request to an endpoint with a method and whatever other options I need attached, e.g. `` axios({ method: `get`, url: `https://foo.bar/baz&q=123`}) ``.

However, I came across this API https://vndb.org/d11 with docs specifying neither the method nor the url (aside from host, which I supposed isn't enough?) where I'm supposed to send my request, so how am I supposed to get any data out of it? Is it possible to access it via Postman or some such?

```
Host api.vndb.org
Port (plain tcp) 19534 ('VN')
Port (TLS) 19535
```

Sample request message looks like:

```
login {
  "protocol" : 1,
  "username" : "ayo"
 }
0x04
```

`0x04` - but this doesn't even look like JSON, so how do I send it across?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [VNDB API documentation](https://vndb.org/d11) it says:

> all communication between the client and the server is done using one
>   TCP connection. This connection stays alive until it is explicitely
>   closed by either the client or the server.

so it's not like a normal REST API where you GET, POST etc. You open a connection and leave it open. It's session based, hence the initial login command and the 0x04 byte at the end of the JSON is the

> End Of Transmission

character. So it works like a two way radio. You say "login, over" where the "over" is the 0x04 byte. That tells the server a command is waiting for it to process. I presume without the 0x04 character the command won't be interpreted. A bit like typing a command and not hitting the return key.

As for how to use the API, you could study this [NodeJS VNDB client](https://github.com/arbauman/vndbjs).